# Upgrade java on Linux Mint 11

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, java

I'm unable to use web-based java content due to my version being out of date.

```
%>java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

There are no updates available through Update Manager, however there are a couple of options on the java download page http://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp?locale=en One is a tarball of the entire java install, another is a .RPM.

Is there a .deb version somewhere?

I'd much prefer having Synaptic handle the updates than try to do it manually and wind up breaking the system update path forever.

Comment: which package manager does Mint use?

Comment: Mint uses Synaptic package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu and can use packages from the Ubuntu repositories (ncluding the many bleeding edge PPAs). Will one of the packages [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/java/) work for you?

In general, to have access to both Mint's and Ubuntu's repositories, your sources list should look something like this:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ katya main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ natty partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ natty free non-free
```

UPDATE:

The sun java jre should be in the ubuntu  partner repository. Do you have this line in your sources.list?

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ natty partner
```

See [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-install-sun-java-runtime-environment-jre-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx.html) for a howto on installing jre on ubuntu (change lucid to natty for Linux Mint 11).

I don't know if the very latest version is in the repos. Are you *sure* you need it? Can you give an example of the kind of content you cannot load?

As an alternative you can try using `alien` to install from rpm. See [here](http://ihaveapc.com/2010/09/how-to-convert-rpm-file-into-deb-file-in-linux-mint/) for a howto.

Comment: Hi - I'm not finding jre1.7.0_07 in the Ubuntu repository in the link you provided.

Comment: @acoder see my updated answer.